# Front end separated from back end project using Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am planning to create a website that has front end and back end. I was wondering how the FE communicates with the BE.

I saw a project that uses Xampp to run the front end and sinatra for the back end. It needs to start apache, then the backend is fired using the `rackup` command. I assume the backend runs under Webrick.

Can someone explain how these two ends communicate with each other? If there is a good tutorial for this, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Sinatra is a popular option for API-only backend applications. We use Grape with Sinatra or just Sinatra without any dependency.

I have two app examples that can help you:

1. https://github.com/katgironpe/sinatra-grape
2. https://github.com/katgironpe/simple-sinatra-mvc

Webrick or Puma can be used with Sinatra, but it's not impossible to run a Ruby app on XAMPP. I did that several years ago. The front-end is probably just consuming the Sinatra API.

You can use Ember CLI project. It can get complex with other options like Angular.js and React.js. Or if you like, just use jQuery.